# How to apply group by or is there any alternative?

Tags: sql

Here is my table

```
id  StudentName SubCode Grade   Stdid
3   leena          1      A       1
4   leena          2      A       1
5   leena          3      B       1
1   pinky          1      A       1
2   pinky          2      A       1
8   smita          1      A       1
7   Megha          1      A       2
6   Rupali         1      A       2
```

Grade are from A to D.I want to show record only once when grade is same for same stid,does not matter what is subcode and studentname.If i am fetching perticular subcode,it's studentname should come.If grade is different for same stid,show both record. Here I want to show

```
StdId Studentname Subcode Grade
1     pinky      2        A
1     leena      3        B
2     Rupali     1        A
```

if i used query like this :

```
  Select Max(StdId) as stid, Max(SubCode) as SubCode,max(Studentname) as Studentname ,Max(Grade) as Grade
From 
Student_Grade
Group By 
StdId, Grade
  ORDER BY Stdid,grade,Studentname,SubCode
```

It gives me output but that is wrong.

```
stid    SubCode Studentname Grade
1        2     smita        A
1        3     leena        B
2        1     Rupali       A
```

If I am fetching smita,value of subcode for smita should come not max.Value of subcode for smita is 1.

I think max should apply either on studentname or subcode not both.If I applied on one, group by will not work.How to handle this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: the issue is not the output but the request: your query is not what's needed to satisfy your request (btw your request is not clear reading your post...). the output is correct when matched against your query; you are performing a very strange query that is doomed to produce that result and does that as requested.

Answer (score 0):

hard to understand the question but

`Select Max(StdId) .... Group By StdId` is definitely not something that you would need. paradox :)

group them by studentName and aggregate the rest

Comment: its absolutely wrong solution. He was facing problem because of that and looking for other solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try ROW_NUMBER() to group by records and then select the required data.

```
;WITH CteFirstGroup AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Stdid,Grade ORDER BY Stdid,Grade) AS GrpStdIdGrade
FROM (
SELECT id
    ,StudentName
    ,SubCode
    ,Grade
    ,Stdid
FROM  Student_Grade)tbltemp),

--get only distinct records group by  Stdid and Grade
SELECT id
    ,StudentName
    ,SubCode
    ,Grade
    ,Stdid FROM CteFirstGroup
WHERE GrpStdIdGrade = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Stdid as StdId, DISTINCT StudentName as Studentname, MAX(SubCode) as Subcode, Grade
FROM  Student_Grade
GROUP BY StudentName
```

Comment: This is not standard SQL and is, in all likelihood, incorrect. Additionally you don't explain why or how this answers the question. Could you?

Comment: @Ben, My bad. Had a really hard time understanding OP's problem. Maybe I shouldn't post answers when I myself is not too sure about the syntax and the problem itself. Thanks for pointing out mate. :)